# PyCharm does not create admin.py in Django project

Tags: django, pycharm

After I created new Django project (with "Enable Django admin" checkbox was checked)
file `admin.py` was not created.

String     `# url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),`
was not uncommented.

What may be the reason for that?
(Windows 7, PyCharm 1.5.3)

Answer (score 0):

Although PyCharm is great overall, there are still little shortcomings throughout the application, and it looks like you've found one of them. I would file a bug on the issue to jetbrains and see if you can get a response.

http://www.jetbrains.com/support/pycharm/

It's looking like their bugtracker is down at the moment though...

Answer (score 0):

`admin.py` is not created because you do not have any models in your applications yet; so the wizard does not know what you want to create admin interfaces for.

The url is not uncommented because you may want to use some other pattern for the admin urls (not everyone wants to use `/admin/`)